# Comparing two arrays - one has to have elements of which all are in the other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example I have an array ["oranges", "apples", "people", "carrots"]

And I have ["oranges", "apples"] - I would like this to be true.
But if it were ["oranges", "shoes"] - I would like this to be false.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please provide a [mcve] so we can help you in a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `every`

```js
const masterArr = ["oranges", "apples", "people", "carrots"];

const arr1 = ["oranges", "apples"];
const arr2 = ["oranges", "shoes"];

const isMatch = (arr, master) => arr.every(e => master.includes(e));

console.log(isMatch(arr1, masterArr));
console.log(isMatch(arr2, masterArr));
```